# $ not defined when running jQuery

Tags: jquery, referenceerror

I have the following code and whenever I load it with HTML, the console gives an error right after loading.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

My script is linked to the HTML file like so: `<script src="src-animation.js"></script>` in the `<head>`.

---

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.play').click(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');
        $(this).append("<h1>Now loading...</h1>");
    });
    $('.not-rdy').click(function(){
        alert("This chapter isn't done yet.\nComing soon!");
        $(this).fadeOut('fast');
    });
    $('#updateCHK').click(function() {
        alert("Server is temporarily unavailable.\nTry again later.");
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Either you aren't loading jQuery before `src-animation.js` or it is in noConflict mode.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara What do you mean by "loading jQuery before `src-animation.js`"?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence of loading the external JavaScript files is important.
You must include the `<script>` for jQuery before the `<script>` for your custom .js file.

So, in the `<head>`

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="src-animation.js"></script>
```

Substitute the proper name of your particular jQuery .js file.

Alternately, you can use a CDN version of the jQuery file. That means that you are causing the client browser to download the jQuery .js file from another web server. In that case, you would do something like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="src-animation.js"></script>
```

Comment: So from what I'm looking at, you have to download the jQuery library before you can use it?

Comment: No, you do not have to download jQuery. You can reference it from a CDN. But that still has to be in a <script> tag before your other .js file's script tag.

Comment: I'm guessing that sourcing from a CDN won't work with offline HTML. Am I right?

Comment: You probably can't rely on the CDN offline, but it is possible for the jQuery library to be downloaded and cached before the user goes offline, in which case it might still be present for offline use.